# Is there a performance difference between these two codes? And which is recommended?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
true ? Icon(Icons.visibility) : Icon(Icons.visibility_off);
Icon(true ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off);
```

Which one is recommended for readability, performance e.t.c.

Comment: Neither?  Each is equivalent to `Icon(Icons.visibility)`.  If you had a boolean variable instead of a boolean literal, the second way is more readable by being less repetitive.  There should be no performance difference.

Comment: I forgot to add: the first way could be slightly more performant if you constructed both `Icon`s as `const`.  The second way (if you used a boolean variable) would be inherently non-`const`.